# How do I configure playwright-jest to exclude a Test Suite (spec) file for a run?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, browser-automation, playwright, e2e

I have a `playwright-jest` setup with multiple spec files (test suites). I need to skip one of them, but it needs to stay in the same directory of its repo (moving it is not an option).

The default script under `package.json` is `"test": "jest -c jest.config.js"` and I know we may run it with `npm run test TestSuiteName.spec.ts` for individual suites, and without a file name - `npm run test`, it runs the entire Test Plan - but - how can I exclude just 1 (or a few) and run the rest of it all?

I have tried to find config flags for it but without luck. What's worked so far is `describe.skip()` for that particular file, and that's mostly what I could come up so far as a decent workaround. However, I don't want to be making changes to the code before every run.

I was hoping to see if anyone has a better way to do it? Regex maybe? Or perhaps through `jest.config` with an option flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found out a regex solution to my problem. It still seems a little less than ideal, but this is better than to add `skip()` in my opinion.

Apparently `jest` makes this pretty easy with just an extra argument to be added with the run command. This argument is treated as a regular expression to match against the Test Suite files in the folder structure.

Providing a pattern as a cli argument, is a way for it to pick only the files matching that regex and executing them -

`jest "my.*(complex)?pattern"`

I had to define a pattern to exclude a string in the file name. Since I wanted to exclude a file with "BVT" text in the file name, adding this to the `package.json` `scripts`, worked in my case -

`"excludeBVT": "jest \"^((?!BVT).)*$\" -c jest.config.js"`